# Why am I getting the error: Skipped 36 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, performance, android-asynctask

I know what the error is trying to say, and I tried using Aysnctask but I still get the error. Here's the code:

Home.java

```
public class Home extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home_act);
    init();

}

void init() {
    findViews();
    changeFont();
    clickListeners();
    assignConditions("category", "all", "1");
    categoryAllApiCall();
}

void assignConditions(String operation, String all, String max_depth) {
    Log.e("assignConditions", "here");
    this.base_url = getResources().getString(R.string.base_url);
    this.file = getResources().getString(R.string.file);
    this.operation_condition = operation;
    this.all_condition = all;
    this.max_depth_condition = max_depth;
}

void categoryAllApiCall() {
    Log.e("categoryAllApiCall", "here");
    RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(base_url).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
    final Category_All category_all = restAdapter.create(Category_All.class);
    category_all.getFeed(file, operation_condition, all_condition, max_depth_condition, new Callback<CategoryPojo>() {
        @Override
        public void success(CategoryPojo categoryPojo, Response response) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            final CategoryPojo category = categoryPojo;
            category_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryId(), category.getCategoryId().length);
            category_name = Arrays.copyOf(category.getCategoryName(), category.getCategoryName().length);
            parent_id = Arrays.copyOf(category.getParentId(), category.getParentId().length);

            new HomeBackgroundTasks().execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            tv_title_header.setText(error.getMessage());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
}

private class HomeBackgroundTasks extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Log.e("doInBackground", "here");
        prepareListData();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Log.e("onPreExecute", "here");
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        Log.e("onPostExecute", "here");
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        setAdapter();
    }

    void prepareListData() {
        Log.e("prepareListData", "here");
        listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        int count = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < category_id.length; i++) {
            List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
            if (parent_id[i].equals("0")) {
                count++;
                listDataHeader.add(category_name[i]);
                for (int j = 0; j < category_id.length; j++) {
                    if (parent_id[j].equals(category_id[i])) {
                        child.add(category_name[j]);

                    }
                }
                listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(count), child);
            }
        }
    }

    void setAdapter() {
        Log.e("setAdapter", "here");
        elv_home_body_lay.setAdapter(new HomeExpandableListAdapter(Home.this, listDataHeader, listDataChild));
    }

}
}
```

HomeExpandableListAdapter.java

```
public class HomeExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

public HomeExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this.listDataChild = listChildData;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon)
{
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_child_items_lay, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

    txtListChild.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoLight(context));

    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
{
    return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).
            size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition)
{
    return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount()
{
    return this.listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition)
{
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.home_group_items_lay, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    ImageView img=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    lblListHeader.setTypeface(EasyFonts.robotoBold(context));

    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    if(isExpanded)
    {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_remove_grey_36pt_2x);
    }
    if(!isExpanded)
    {
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_grey_36pt_2x);
    }

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds()
{
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return true;
}
}
```

And heres the LogCat:

```
08-01 20:02:29.470  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject E/assignConditions﹕ here
08-01 20:02:29.471  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject E/categoryAllApiCall﹕ here
08-01 20:02:31.796  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject E/onPreExecute﹕ here
08-01 20:02:31.797  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 61 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-01 20:02:31.806  13853-14215/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject E/doInBackground﹕ here
08-01 20:02:31.806  13853-14215/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject E/prepareListData﹕ here
08-01 20:02:32.581  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject E/onPostExecute﹕ here
08-01 20:02:32.581  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject E/setAdapter﹕ here
08-01 20:02:32.597  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.614  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.629  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.642  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.656  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.670  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.687  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.867  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:32.887  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:02:33.501  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-01 20:03:01.272  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:03:01.354  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:03:01.437  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:03:01.553  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
08-01 20:03:01.707  13853-13853/com.piddlybox.www.mypiddyboxproject D/FontSourceProcessor﹕ Successfully loaded font.
```

I would like the app to perform faster, this is where I have gotten so far. Can someone please help me solve this error.

Thank You

Comment: Use Traceview to determine exactly where your problem lies.

Comment: Ok, i will check it out, Is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: The barrage of "Successfully loaded font" messages suggests that `EasyFonts` may be something to investigate. Also, it looks like you are doing network I/O on the main application thread in `categoryAllApiCall()`. That should be crashing with a `NetworkOnMainThreadError`.

Comment: Ok, but when I put the categoryAllApiCall in the doInBackground(). I just get multiple skipping errors and it doesn't display anything. Can you suggest a way to show me how to do it? Code will surely help, Thanks